# Rendering an Array of Data with map() and JSX to [[]]

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have a function in `JSX` that stores value gotten from a `database` thus:

```
const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
               this.setState({ data: data });
```

The response format is:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Avengers: Infinity War","year":2018},{"id":5,"name":"Thor: Ragnarock","year":2017},{"id":6,"name":"Black Panther","year":2018},{"id":7,"name":"Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker","year":2019}]
```

However, I am trying to use a `react` `table control` that expects the data to be in this format:

```
const data = [
     ['1st column', '2nd column', '3rd column'],
     ['1st cell', '2nd cell', '3rd cell']
 ]

 render() {
 <ReactTabllist 
             data={data} 
             property={property} />
 }
```

So I need to turn the `JSON` into an `javascript` `array` of arrays. What is a good way to do this?

```
const data = this.state.data.map(movie => ( /* what goes here? */ ));
```

Comment: what's the response format?

Comment: See original post I edited to show the response [format].

Comment: Object.values(movie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per I understand, you need to get every property in the JSON and then put the values of every element into the `data`-react property.

So, first you would need to make sure, the response from the database is well formatted, and that every element in the json-parsed `responseText` is the same as the rest of them.

With that into account:

```
const formattedData = this
    .state
    .data
    .map(movie => Object.keys(movie).map(key => movie[key]));
```

And that `formattedData` is what you want to pass as react-attribute of `data={formattedData}`

Alternatively, if you don't care about the keys of the movie whatsoever, you could do as @Madmadi has suggested:

```
const formattedData = this
    .state
    .data
    .map(movie => Object.values(movie));
```

Comment: Redundant, use Object.values instead

Comment: I prefer to use keys, because sometimes you need the key name too... but for this example, it's true, `Object#values` does the job without the extra steps.